# Typescript for a promise that resolves an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, promise

I'd like to generally declare that a function returns a promise that resolves an array of objects (I think that this would resolve a TS error; TS doesn't know that I can use `forEach` on the resolved array).

On the function `openJSON()` (see below) I tried things like:

```
function OpenJSON(): Promise<Array<{id: string, performance: number, average: number}>> { // ...
```

but I still get errors. And in the future, I expect all sorts of different objects to be produced by this function. Is there just a general way to declare an array of objects, say like `Promise<Array<{}>>`?

```
async function produceDataRows() {
   let tableContent = '';
   let jsonData = await OpenJSON();

   // error occurs here: [ts] Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'.
   jsonData.forEach(element => {
       // convert this JSON data into table content
   });
   return tableContent;
};

function OpenJSON() {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      fs.open(kJsonPath, 'wx', (err, fd) => {
         if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'EEXIST') {
               fs.readFile(kJsonPath, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  resolve(JSON.parse(content));
               })
            } else {
               reject( new Error('When openening performance.JSON, in generateHTML.js, an unexpected error has occured. ' + err) );
            }
         } else throw Error('There is a problem opening performance.JSON');
      })
   })
}
```

Comment: doesn't typescript have some keyword that allows you to specify `any` type?

Comment: The original error was `[ts] Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'`. Now I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` with something like Promise<Array<any>>

Comment: It compiles fine [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20x()%3A%20Promise%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20z()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20y%20%3D%20await%20x()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y.forEach(n%20%3D%3E%20console.log(n))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A). `Promise<Array<any>>` or `Promise<any[]>` is the right type for `OpenJSON`, by the looks of it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it does, but not with `--noImplicitAny`. Anyway, it is not necessary to use `any` unless you want to convey that you don't know what the JSON looks like.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to specify the result type when you construct the promise itself.

```
function OpenJSON() {
    return new Promise<Array<{ id: string, performance: number, average: number }>>(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            fs.open(kJsonPath, 'wx', (err, fd) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.code === 'EEXIST') {
                        fs.readFile(kJsonPath, 'utf8', (err, content) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            }
                            resolve(JSON.parse(content));
                        })
                    } else {
                        reject(Error('When openening performance.JSON'));
                    }
                } else {
                    reject(Error('There is a problem opening performance.JSON'));
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Note in the above, I fixed several error handling issues.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20var%20kJsonPath%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20fs%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20open(path%3A%20string%2C%20x%3A%20string%2C%20callback%3A%20Function)%3A%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readFile(path%3A%20string%2C%20x%3A%20string%2C%20callback%3A%20Function)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20OpenJSON()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3CArray%3C%7B%20id%3A%20string%2C%20performance%3A%20number%2C%20average%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fs.open(kJsonPath%2C%20'wx'%2C%20(err%2C%20fd)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(err.code%20%3D%3D%3D%20'EEXIST')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fs.readFile(kJsonPath%2C%20'utf8'%2C%20(err%2C%20content)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(err)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(JSON.parse(content))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(Error('When%20openening%20performance.JSON'))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(Error('There%20is%20a%20problem%20opening%20performance.JSON'))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20produceDataRows()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20tableContent%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20jsonData%20%3D%20await%20OpenJSON()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%20occurs%20here%3A%20%5Bts%5D%20Property%20'forEach'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'%7B%7D'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20jsonData.forEach(element%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20convert%20this%20JSON%20data%20into%20table%20content%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tableContent%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've pasted in your code but now this error appears: `(node:13688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function`

Comment: @chamilton that is because I fixed some bugs where you were not converting the errors to rejections in the promise callbacks. Your code is throwing an error.

Comment: Cool, and thanks for the link @Aluan Haddad . I'll see if I can sort out the errors.

Comment: @unional: I'm pretty sure your edit introduced a syntax errors. What's the reason?